# Eclipse does not start after download - Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-12.04

I had recently downloaded the Eclipse Platform SR2 Kepler edition from the eclipse foundation website. However after unpacking the tarball I tried to open it by simply double clicking on the "eclipse" file. But it does not start. What could be the problem ?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible reasons:

- missing libraries or version mismatch
- 64/32bit mismatch
- bad permissions
- lack of disk space
- no memory
- left directories from a previous installation

For first, **try to run it in a terminal** and watch the output.

There are also a pre-defined packages from ubuntu. The main package is called just 'eclipse'. Normally, you can assume they work out of the box.